# NuxtJS static generation date-fns "locale must contain localize property" + nuxt-i18n

Tags: nuxt.js, date-fns, nuxt-i18n

I've recently added the `@nuxtjs/date-fns` module to my app. My goal was to format in different languages a date into a human-readable format like "Friday, 13th of July 2042".

For language translation, I am using the `@nuxtjs/i18n` module.

Here is the problematic chunk of code when I try to generate statically:

```js
{{
   $dateFns.format($dateFns.addDays(new Date(startDate), 30), "PP", {
     locale: $i18n.locale
   })
}}
```

I always get the following error from the `date-fns` module:

```
 WARN  [date-fns] locale 'en' not found.                                            09:00:32
 ERROR   /en/offices/ecos-pfaffikon-sz                                              09:00:32
RangeError: locale must contain localize property
    at Object.format (/home/gno/open2work/nuxt/node_modules/date-fns/format/index.js:382:11)
    at Object.dateObj.format (node_modules/.cache/nuxt/date-fns.js:31:0)
    at a.render (components/TabFix.vue?b9bd:1:0)
    at a.t._render (/home/gno/open2work/nuxt/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.prod.js:6:35346)
    at /home/gno/open2work/nuxt/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.prod.js:1:70916
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:58:5)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:525:9)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:499:7)
```

I've already tried to wrap the chunk of code into `<client-only></client-only>` without any successful result.

Everything works properly when I am on dev mode. I think the problem may lie in the generation process, and there is certainly a conflict between the client-side and server-side.

Also my nuxt.config.js

```js
 dateFns: {
    methods: ["format", "differenceInMinutes", "addDays"],
    locales: ["en", "de", "fr"],
    fallbackLocale: "en"
  },
"nuxt-i18n",
      {
        seo: false,
        detectBrowserLanguage: {
          useCookie: true,
          cookieKey: "i18n_redirected",
          onlyOnRoot: true
        },
        langDir: "lang/",
        lazy: true,
        locales: [
          {
            code: "en",
            iso: "en-US",
            file: "en.js"
          },
          {
            code: "de",
            iso: "de-DE",
            file: "de.js"
          },
          {
            code: "fr",
            iso: "fr-FR",
            file: "fr.js"
          }
        ],
        vueI18n: {
          fallbackLocale: "de"
        },
        defaultLocale: "de",
        strategy: "prefix",
        parsePages: false
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I've just gone through it. It indeed works this way, however I would have thought that the nuxtjs package would have imported it automatically by adding the parameters in the nuxt.config.js.

Comment: For performance (lazy-loading), this is not importing the whole 40 or so locales. Maybe some clever way of binding it to the i18n locale could have helped, but it's not the case so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the error `en` is not an available locale.

More info on the docs here: https://date-fns.org/v2.22.1/docs/I18n
`date-fns` use more of a `enUS` or `enGB` format for it's locales.

If you import it into your component, it uses a `en-GB` format, even worse I know..

[image]

Comment: Do you have any clue how to use in [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/)

Comment: @Krisna the question here is on `date-fns`, would probably be a good idea to create a new one about luxon since it's something totally different.

Comment: True story. Sorry for that